# "Go to help" vs. just "help"

Tags: meaning

In the book that I am reading, there is the sentence

> let me go to help him

which means

> I will go to help him

In this sentence, I don't know why there is "go to".

What is difference between this and "I will help him"?

Comment: You could perhaps ***help him*** simply by staying in your seat and making a telephone call. But if you ***go to help him*** that would imply you getting up and going somewhere (almost certainly, to wherever "he" is, which is where you would render assistance).

Answer (score 3):

Most likely the difference is that in the prior example, "Let me go to help him" the speaker is saying that need to travel some distance, perhaps only a few feet, but still they are not able to help without first getting to the place.

It's hard to say though without the full context. I would also be careful saying that "let me go help him" means "I will go help him." Let seems to indicate that the speaker is asking for permission perhaps rhetorically but still asking.

Comment: ah.... It means I go to him and help him is the first one and if the one who need to helping is in front of I, I can just help him with out going right?

Comment: @EricHa The difference is more in the speaker's intention rather than the actual distance involved. Using "go to" puts emphasis on the traveling part. Of course, you can't *go* if the person is so close that you literally don't have to move in order to help them.

Comment: @Era: In some contexts, *to go to help* could be a loose figurative usage meaning *to **start to do** something [but then not in fact complete the action]*. It doesn't *always* have to imply physical movement, but I think in the context of OP's question here it's probably good enough to say it [nearly] always does.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Very good point. That's a common idiomatic usage of the phrase, as in for example *"I went to shut the door, but it had been blown off its hinges by a tornado."*

Comment: @Era: In *that* example we could reasonably say you "definitely ***moved***", even if you didn't get as far as the door (but you *might* have even gotten that far before realizing you couldn't close it). But with, say, [*He went to light a cigarette*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he+went+to+light+a+cigarette%22) it's quite possible he never "went" anywhere at all. He might just have been sitting in his chair and realising as he reached for his cigarettes that he was in a no-smoking office. Maybe he only *thought* about lighting up - certainly at most he only moved his *hands*.